# keytool error:keystore file exists but is empty

Tags: android, google-maps, android-keystore

I developed an Android application which uses Google Maps API as my graduation project.

I have to publish it on Google Play, so I tried to create an signed APK. I'm doing this via Android Studio's generate signed apk tool. It's okey to creating key. But when i use that signed apk, the map doesn't work. So, I searched on the internet and I found that I have to change my API key with SHA1 fingerprint. But when I tried to take it from the command line with this;

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\esrau\Desktop\keygrad\keygrad6 -alias EmuGrad -storepass urla259/ -keypass urla259/
```

I took that error:

[image: error]

I already tried every solution on the internet, so i tried the SHA1 key from the gradle>android>signingReport. It gives same error.

I also tried create new API Key from the release>values>google_maps_api.xml
[image: google_maps_api]

It again gives same error. None of the solutions worked for me.

So, any suggestions will be accepted. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday, and generated it using java. Be sure to put your package name.

```
public static void showHashKey(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.example.yourpackagename", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES); //Your            package name here
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.i("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used it on my first activity and call it like  showHashKey(getApplicationContext() );
 so it gives me something like: 
KeyHash:: F7on3pxubJUKvuwvVHzakVAlnac 
Am I using it right? And what I'm going to do with that keyhash?

Comment: I guess that this link: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Generating_a_Signed_Release_APK_File_in_Android_Studio might definitely help you.

Comment: Ok, and this: keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000